# Is it possible to call Multiple xml layout using one main activity without creating new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have 10  layouts without `.java` file. I want to call all layouts using button. Is it possible to do with having only one `MainActivity` `.java` file means can we use multiple `setContentView` ?

Comment: use **`Fragments`**

Comment: you can do it through `FRAGMENTS`

Answer (score 1):

Include your all layout in your main layout and make `visibility GONE` for all other layout. And based on button click you can display any particular layout based on layout ID.

Sample xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<!--    main layout for first time loading activity-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

    <!--    Display layout based on button click-->
<LinearLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

    <!--    Display layout based on button click-->
<LinearLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

    <!--    Display layout based on button click-->
<LinearLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/layout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Memory consumption will be a nightmare that way, fragment it's the ideal solution even though it's kind of missing the point of layout without extra java file

Comment: @ Moshe Edri Yes i agree about memory consumption, but i given solution based on his requirement as he don't need more then one java file.

Answer (score 0):

You can not provide more than one layout to any activity, but if you want to use the different layout files in one activity than you can include all layout files into a single layout file using  tag and use them in you activity.

Comment: would be better to use fragments instead

Comment: yes it is , you can use the fragments to show different views in the activity, which is core concept of fragment but what if you want all your view(different layout view ) in your single mainActivity.

If you requirement is not showing all the view at same time you can use the fragment. It is depend upon the UI requirement wether use fragment or include the layout in xml.

Comment: I would still not say to use that kind of pattern. Imagine how many lines of findviewbyId you have to write if you have 10 layouts in one activity

Comment: you can use databinding to avoid the findviewbyid , and use the different class to handle the onClicklistner that will help you to hide your main logic from the activity class and less line in the activity, but still it also depend upon the requirement if you want to use fragment it is the best practise.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>
```

titlebar is different layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/titlebar_bg"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
```

include in main layout like this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" /></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fragments for this.

Simply , declare one FrameLayout in your Main Activity Layout.

And create Fragments for each layout you want.

Now, you can switch layouts using Fragment Manager.

Refer this for more details : [Here](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture09/lecture09.html)

Hope it Helps !!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use multiple `setContentView()` in to single activity.

if you just want to add the other xml layouts to another. you can use the `<include>` tag.

Example:

**layout_one.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is layout one"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_two.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is layout two"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_one">/>
    <include layout="@layout/layout_two">/>
</LinearLayout>
```